# Display bootstrap modal after successful create action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic email entry form on my home page, and if the subscriber's email is saved I want redirect them back and display a bootstrap modal with some info. I've thought about sending a `flash[:success]` to the view and then saying, "If `flash[:success]`, display modal," but I'm not sure what the right way is to actually trigger the modal.

*/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:*

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save
    # Send info to view (a flash?) saying to show modal
    redirect_to root_path
...
```

If it matters:

- The view is */views/pages/home.html.erb*.
- We can use `subscriber-success-modal` (or whatever's easiest) for the modal id.
- We can use `subscriber_success_modal.html.erb` for the partial view with modal.

Comment: This might not be a ideal solution but . you can send a query string with root_url like `?modal=true` then in home page , use JS to check the query string presence of modal=true and then you can show modal using required code `modal.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

as you are redirecting a user you can not use the instance variables to share the data between requests, for this you have to use session to store the value of the show modal key like:

`session[:show_modal] =  true`

and in the html file "/views/pages/home.html.erb" you can get session variable show_modal and can show modals accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. What's the simplest way to actually go about displaying / triggering the modal? Something like the below doesn't seem to work.
      `<% if session[:show_modal] == true %>
        <%= render "layouts/success_modal" %>
      <% end %>`
I'm guessing there's some JS involved?

Comment: Please see above.